# How to improve startup time of OpenRC system?

Tags: startup, gentoo, openrc

My [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/get-started/about/) system with [OpenRC init](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC) takes a long time to start, about 24 seconds (measured from [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) to [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager)). I was wondering if there are any recommended ways how to improve this time. But there isn't much about this topic on the internet, what I found.

I have an Intel Core i5-6400 and a Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everybody loves fast system startups, especially on a daily used desktop computer. 24 seconds is quite a slow startup time and I was able to reduce it to **9 seconds**.

I will show you a few tips, with no need to touch your kernel.

### /etc/rc.conf

Let's start with the OpenRC configuration file. There is an option called `rc_parallel`. By default, services are started one by one and when some service takes more time, it delays others. Setting `rc_parallel="YES"` allows the RC system to try and start services in parallel for a slight speed improvement. In my case, it was -5 seconds.

A also had to set `rc_send_sighup="YES"`, `rc_timeout_stopsec="10"`, `rc_send_sigkill="YES"`, because  xdm service [didn't want to stop](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gentoo/comments/eic8ky/waiting_for_xdm_how_can_i_fix_this/) while shutting down the system.

### rc-service, rc-update

Another important thing is to know, what services are actually starting. That's the output you see during startup. If you want to [log this output](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenRC#Boot_logs), set `rc_logger="YES"` in `/etc/rc.conf` file. You can find here exact times, warning messages or errors.

Services are divided into so-called [runlevels](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC#Runlevels), which means the period, when are these services started. There are two runlevels involved in system startup. `boot` and `default`.

You can list all services and their runlevels with the command: `rc-update show`.
Or you can list all running and stopped services with: `rc-status --servicelist`

In my case, I found a few unnecessary services which I could safely disable. For example `bluetooth`, `netmount` or `net.enp0s31f6` service to set my network interface. It was enabled even tho I use `NetworkManager` service. I didn't need these services and got another 10 seconds down by disabling them.

You can disable service in specific runlevel with the command: `rc-update del <service> <runlevel>`.

Always **check, what a particular service does**, before disabling it. You could end up with a broken system.

---

I hope this could help someone and save a little time I had to spend.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `app-shells/dash` package, and then making the `/bin/sh` symlink point to `dash`.  The latter can be done manually or with the `eselect sh` subcommand.

The first distro which did this by default was Ubuntu more than 10 years ago (IIRC) and it made a bigger difference than trying to run the initscript in parallel, as the other answer recommends.

Comment: Great tip, thank you! I just tested it and it's approximately a 1-second improvement.

Comment: Without `rc_parallel` it is about 14 seconds. With `rc_parallel` enabled, about 8 seconds. I guess on CPUs 10 years ago wasn't `rc_parallel` so effective as on today's multicores.